# MySQL null variable not returning correct case

Tags: mysql, null, scope, case

Below I have the set up for a procedure that will loop using the parameters. However, I was testing it parts of it but was getting an unwanted output.

When I chose for p_start to be null, the select v_start output would state v_start is NULL. But I thought having a case statement would redefine v_start as 1 instead...

Any suggestions? Thanks.

```
Create procedure counter_loop( p_start int, 
                               p_end int,
                               p_step int, 
                               p_delim varchar(5))
begin
declare v_start int ;
declare v_end int ;
declare v_step int ;
declare v_sign int;


-- check p_start
case p_start
when null then
    set v_start := 1;
else
    set v_start := p_start;
end case;

 select v_start;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

syntax was wrong... when checking p_start for null case... check with IS NULL.

```
 case 
 when **p_start is** null then
    set v_start := 1;
 else
    set v_start := p_start;
 end case;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are calling the stored procedure are you saying declaring p_start parameter as null? or passing an empty string?

exec counter_loop(null,10,2,'abc') then I think your null case will catch it.

I would recommend you using an integer check on p_start instead of null.

Some thing like:

```
CASE p_start when (len(p_start) > 0 and p_start > 0)  then ...
```

Comment: when i call counter_loop(null,10,2,'abc') , i get that p_start is null.  but i want it to come out as 1. if i use the proc of the length comparison, does that help? i mean length(null) is null, not positive...